# Executing SSIS package crashes Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ssis

I run into a problem, when I try to execute a SSIS package from Visual Studio either by "Execute package" from solution explorer, or "Execute task" from designer itself, there is an error that states "visual studio encountered a problem and needs to close" and it restarts. After restart I've noticed that input files for package are inaccessible because two tasks "SSIS debug host" and "SSIS debug host 32bit" are still running.

Funny part is, that in one try out of let say ten, everything goes ok...

In Event viewer I've found two events that link to this problem:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3ac1

My specification:
-VS2010 Ultimate with SP1
-SQL 2012 Developer with SP1
-Win8.1

I've tried to reinstall VS and repair installation of SQL and it didn't worked.

Any thoughts what to check?

Comment: What task are you executing? Have you downloaded the VS 2010 Service Pack like the [url](http://oca.microsoft.com/resredir.aspx?SID=19200&iBucketTable=5&iBucket=94489458087&BucketHash=49c4bf9919486ad08f7046a8f84b6c24) in your posted Event Log specifies?

Comment: This url gives me 404, but as I stated before, I installed the service pack for VS. It doesn't matter which task I tried to execute, even executing whole package produced same error.

BUT:
I found a way to walk around this issue:
Apparently, this error occures, when I try to execute packages when i have opened whole solution with many other projects in it, but when I open only single SSIS project in VS, everything works as usual... This is strange but work for now, still the whole thing is mysterious and unresolved..

Comment: The URL redirects to http://wer.microsoft.com/responses/Response.aspx/19200/en/5.1.2600.0.00000000.9.9?SGD=329454cc-27d9-4de3-a638-8879edd73661&iBucketTable=5&iBucket=94489458087&BucketHash=49c4bf9919486ad08f7046a8f84b6c24 Anyways, patch your VS instance and then see if it doesn't go away. Probably won't hurt to patch your SQL Server bits as well. I'm on CU7 for SQL Server 2012 as it eliminates a jiggling issue with the SSIS designer for the 2012 VS install.

Comment: Will do and will report if that helped or not, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what happened to work for me in my situation:
I had to create a separate solution file, that consist only SSIS projects and Datacube projects, then was able to execute packages within Visual Studio without random crashes.